# Шаблон Executor для получения нескольких записей и выполнения препаред стейтментов

Tags: java, база-данных, postgresql, шаблоны-проектирования

Пишу такую обертку для работы с постгресом:

```
package pg;

import java.sql.*;

public class Executor {
    public <T> T execQuery(String query, ResultHandler<T> handler) {
        try (Statement st = PGConnection.getConnection().createStatement()) {
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);
            T result = handler.handle(rs);
            rs.close();
            return result;
        }
        catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}


package pg;

import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public interface ResultHandler<T> {
    T handle(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException;
}
```

Смысл в том, чтобы можно было одной строчкой получать результат определенного типа, имплементировав интерфейс для преобразования ResultSet'а в этот тип. Увидел ограничения этого паттерна:

1. Непонятно, как использовать prepared стейтменты с плейсхолдерами для параметров
2. Непонятно, как экзекутором получить List результатов одного типа (несколько записей из постгреса, сконвертированных в объект)

Возможно ли такое улучшение этого паттерна?

Вот почему мне не нравится реализовать свои идеи о том, как это делать: если писать так, как мне представляется правильным, получится не Executor, а обычное DAO. Executor, вроде бы, нечто более специализированное и позволяет уменьшить количество кода.

Comment: вы изобретаете [`JdbcTemplate`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html) из Spring?

Comment: @zRrr, да, не хочу тащить спринг в микротулзу ради одной функции.